# Popup.js Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML is like this

```
<div class="container">
          <p>MANHATTAN ...<a href="#" class="poper">Read More</a></p>
          <p class="popup" style="display:none" >some text</p>
  </div>
 <div class="container">
          <p>washington...<a href="#" class="poper">Read More</a></p>
          <p class="popup" style="display:none" >some text 2</p>
  </div>
```

I am using  [Popup.js](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/) to make a popup on this like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
        $(function(){
        $('.poper').popup({
             content : $(this).parents('.container').find(".popup")
           });
    });
 </script>
```

But it is not working. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

**Note:** References to Jquery and Popup JS is already added. Which is not shown Here

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7yX4/)

Comment: *References to Jquery and Popup JS is already added.* What about the CSS file? And NOT WORKING is too broad, see what your console says and post the error here

Comment: plz create your jsfiddle so that we can solve your problem

Comment: @NiravPrajapati Fiddle is made http://jsfiddle.net/Z7yX4/

Comment: @Mr.Alien CSS is also added. And Console does not show any error. I have made a fiddle now. Please check it
http://jsfiddle.net/Z7yX4/

Comment: The question's a bit general, but there is one clear solution to this problem - Athul just needs to change his popup init function as I've suggested, for the reasons I mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should say:

```
$('.poper').popup({
    content : function(e){
        return $(this.ele).closest('.container').find(".popup").text()
    }
});
```

The problem was the value of the "this" keyword in your selector

```
$(this).parents('.container').find(".popup")
```

Because of how the Popup.js plugin works, when the user clicks the link, the value of "this" is the Popup object, not the clicked link. For example if you add a console.log line to your fiddle

```
content : function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(this).parents('.container').find(".popup")
}
```

And click on the link, Popup is logged in the console, not the link element. Because "this" is not the clicked link as you expect, your JS doesn't find the .popup element.

Popup.js keeps a reference to the popup trigger element as this.ele. So change your init function as mentioned and it'll work.

---

MORE DETAILS ON POPUP.JS

The plugin documentation doesn't tell you as much as it should, so in case anybody else will find them useful, here's a few more details:

In its more basic form, the plugin does a request for whatever's in the href attribute of the link and displays it in the popup.

Using this example from the Popup page

`<a href="http://placehold.it/350x150.png" class="popup">Image 1</a>`

The placeholder image opens in the popup.

Similarly, this example

`<a href="http://toddish.co.uk" class="default_popup">Default External Site</a>`

Makes a request to `http://toddish.co.uk` and loads the results inside the popup.

But when you give Popup.js links with the href attribute # you need to give it the content another way.

In this situation, you can pass the content in your popup() initialisation in the "content" option. For example, you can create an anonymous function which returns a string to "content". This works:

```
$('.popupContent').popup({
    content : function(){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
});
```

You can also specify the desired content as a string, if you add a type option to set the content type:

```
$('.html_popup').popup({
  content : '<h1>This is some HTML</h1>',
  type : 'html'
});
```

Alternatively, you can also hide your content in a hidden element, give it a unique ID and use that ID in the href attribute of your popup link, for example:

```
<p id="popText" style="display:none">some text</p>
```

and link

```
<a href="#popText" class="poper">Link text</a>
```

and

```
$('.poper').popup();
```

Popup.js will take the content of the hidden element and display it in the popup when the user clicks.

Looks like a nice script, the developer's just not explained everything!